# Background image of email template is not working in outlook any version

Tags: javascript, html, css, email, outlook

I have created an email template with some `foreground` and `background` images.
I  got that the `background` images not accepted by outlook except in `body` tag.
I just want to implement `background` for `header` and `footer`

Has any one have any alternate solution for that.
I spent so much time but didn't get any luck.

**Some one has given an alternate for that with `background` images with `td tag`
this is the [Link](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/forums/topic/3862/please-test-this-outlook-20072010-background-image-solution/)**

unfortunately it doesn't work for me may be I did something wrong, because I don't have more knowledge about `HTML` and `CSS`

I have taken a responsive template and modified it as my requirement

Here is my `template` code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" /> <!-- disable auto telephone linking in iOS -->
        <title>Respmail is a response HTML email designed to work on all major email platforms and smartphones</title>
        <style type="text/css">
        /* RESET STYLES */
        body, #bodyTable, #bodyCell, #bodyCell{height:100% !important; margin:0; padding:0; width:100% !important;font-family:Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;}
        table{border-collapse:collapse;}
        table[id=bodyTable] {width:100%!important;margin:auto;max-width:500px!important;color:#7A7A7A;font-weight:normal;}
        img, a img{border:0; outline:none; text-decoration:none;height:auto; line-height:100%;}
        a {text-decoration:none !important;border-bottom: 1px solid;}
        h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6{color:#5F5F5F; font-weight:normal; font-family:Helvetica; font-size:20px; line-height:125%; text-align:Left; letter-spacing:normal;margin-top:0;margin-right:0;margin-bottom:10px;margin-left:0;padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-left:0;padding-right:0;}
        /* CLIENT-SPECIFIC STYLES */
        .ReadMsgBody{width:100%;} .ExternalClass{width:100%;} /* Force Hotmail/Outlook.com to display emails at full width. */
        .ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div{line-height:100%;} /* Force Hotmail/Outlook.com to display line heights normally. */
        table, td{mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;} /* Remove spacing between tables in Outlook 2007 and up. */
        #outlook a{padding:0;} /* Force Outlook 2007 and up to provide a "view in browser" message. */
        img{-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;display:block;outline:none; text-decoration:none;} /* Force IE to smoothly render resized images. */
        body, table, td, p, a, li, blockquote{-ms-text-size-adjust:100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; font-weight:normal!important;} /* Prevent Windows- and Webkit-based mobile platforms from changing declared text sizes. */
        .ExternalClass td[class="ecxflexibleContainerBox"] h3 {padding-top: 10px !important;} /* Force hotmail to push 2-grid sub headers down */
        /* /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/ TEMPLATE STYLES /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/ */
        /* ========== Page Styles ========== */
        h1{display:block;font-size:26px;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;line-height:100%;}
        h2{display:block;font-size:20px;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;line-height:120%;}
        h3{display:block;font-size:17px;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;line-height:110%;}
        h4{display:block;font-size:18px;font-style:italic;font-weight:normal;line-height:100%;}
        .flexibleImage{height:auto;}
        .linkRemoveBorder{border-bottom:0 !important;}
        table[class=flexibleContainerCellDivider] {padding-bottom:0 !important;padding-top:0 !important;}
        body, #bodyTable{background-color:#E1E1E1;}
        #emailHeader{background-color:#E1E1E1;}
        #emailBody{background-color:#FFFFFF;}
        #emailFooter{background-color:#E1E1E1;}
        .textContent, .textContentLast{color:#8B8B8B; font-family:Helvetica; font-size:16px; line-height:125%; text-align:Left;}
        .textContent a, .textContentLast a{color:#205478; text-decoration:underline;}
        .nestedContainer{background-color:#F8F8F8; border:1px solid #CCCCCC;}
        .emailButton{background-color:#205478; border-collapse:separate;}
        .buttonContent{color:#FFFFFF; font-family:Helvetica; font-size:18px; font-weight:bold; line-height:100%; padding:15px; text-align:center;}
        .buttonContent a{color:#FFFFFF; display:block; text-decoration:none!important; border:0!important;}
        .emailCalendar{background-color:#FFFFFF; border:1px solid #CCCCCC;}
        .emailCalendarMonth{background-color:#205478; color:#FFFFFF; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px; font-weight:bold; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px; text-align:center;}
        .emailCalendarDay{color:#205478; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:60px; font-weight:bold; line-height:100%; padding-top:20px; padding-bottom:20px; text-align:center;}
        .imageContentText {margin-top: 10px;line-height:0;}
        .imageContentText a {line-height:0;}
        #invisibleIntroduction {display:none !important;} /* Removing the introduction text from the view */
        /*FRAMEWORK HACKS & OVERRIDES */
        span[class=ios-color-hack] a {color:#275100!important;text-decoration:none!important;} /* Remove all link colors in IOS (below are duplicates based on the color preference) */
        span[class=ios-color-hack2] a {color:#205478!important;text-decoration:none!important;}
        span[class=ios-color-hack3] a {color:#8B8B8B!important;text-decoration:none!important;}
        /* A nice and clean way to target phone numbers you want clickable and avoid a mobile phone from linking other numbers that look like, but are not phone numbers.  Use these two blocks of code to "unstyle" any numbers that may be linked.  The second block gives you a class to apply with a span tag to the numbers you would like linked and styled.
        Inspired by Campaign Monitor's article on using phone numbers in email: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3571/using-phone-numbers-in-html-email/.
        */
        .a[href^="tel"], a[href^="sms"] {text-decoration:none!important;color:#606060!important;pointer-events:none!important;cursor:default!important;}
        .mobile_link a[href^="tel"], .mobile_link a[href^="sms"] {text-decoration:none!important;color:#606060!important;pointer-events:auto!important;cursor:default!important;}
        /* MOBILE STYLES */
        @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
        /*////// CLIENT-SPECIFIC STYLES //////*/
        body{width:100% !important; min-width:100% !important;} /* Force iOS Mail to render the email at full width. */
        /* FRAMEWORK STYLES */
        /*
        CSS selectors are written in attribute
        selector format to prevent Yahoo Mail
        from rendering media query styles on
        desktop.
        */
        table[id="emailHeader"], table[id="emailBody"], table[id="emailFooter"], table[class="flexibleContainer"] {width:100% !important;}
        td[class="flexibleContainerBox"], td[class="flexibleContainerBox"] table {display: block;width: 100%;text-align: left;}
        /*
        The following style rule makes any
        image classed with 'flexibleImage'
        fluid when the query activates.
        Make sure you add an inline max-width
        to those images to prevent them
        from blowing out.
        */
        td[class="imageContent"] img {height:auto !important; width:100% !important; max-width:100% !important;}
        img[class="flexibleImage"]{height:auto !important; width:100% !important;max-width:100% !important;}
        img[class="flexibleImageSmall"]{height:auto !important; width:auto !important;}
        /*
        Create top space for every second element in a block
        */
        table[class="flexibleContainerBoxNext"]{padding-top: 10px !important;}
        /*
        Make buttons in the email span the
        full width of their container, allowing
        for left- or right-handed ease of use.
        */
        table[class="emailButton"]{width:100% !important;}
        td[class="buttonContent"]{padding:0 !important;}
        td[class="buttonContent"] a{padding:15px !important;}
        }
        /*  CONDITIONS FOR ANDROID DEVICES ONLY
        *   http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/targeting.html
        *   http://pugetworks.com/2011/04/css-media-queries-for-targeting-different-mobile-devices/ ;
        =====================================================*/
        @media only screen and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio:.75){
        /* Put CSS for low density (ldpi) Android layouts in here */
        }
        @media only screen and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio:1){
        /* Put CSS for medium density (mdpi) Android layouts in here */
        }
        @media only screen and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio:1.5){
        /* Put CSS for high density (hdpi) Android layouts in here */
        }
        /* end Android targeting */
        /* CONDITIONS FOR IOS DEVICES ONLY
        =====================================================*/
        @media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width:568px) {
        }
        /* end IOS targeting */
        </style>
        <!--
        Outlook Conditional CSS
        These two style blocks target Outlook 2007 & 2010 specifically, forcing
        columns into a single vertical stack as on mobile clients. This is
        primarily done to avoid the 'page break bug' and is optional.
        More information here:
        http://templates.mailchimp.com/development/css/outlook-conditional-css
        -->
        <!--[if mso 12]>
        <style type="text/css">
        .flexibleContainer{display:block !important; width:100% !important;}
        </style>
        <![endif]-->
        <!--[if mso 14]>
        <style type="text/css">
        .flexibleContainer{display:block !important; width:100% !important;}
        </style>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#eef0f2" leftmargin="0" marginwidth="0" topmargin="0" marginheight="0" offset="0">
        <center style="background-color:#eef0f2;">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="100%" id="bodyTable" style="table-layout: fixed;max-width:100% !important;width: 100% !important;min-width: 100% !important;">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" id="bodyCell">
                    <table bgcolor="#eef0f2;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="500" id="emailHeader">
                        <!-- HEADER ROW // -->
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">
                                <!-- CENTERING TABLE // -->
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="center" valign="top">
                                            <!-- FLEXIBLE CONTAINER // -->
                                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="500" class="flexibleContainer">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td valign="top" width="500" class="flexibleContainerCell">
                                                        <!-- CONTENT TABLE // -->
                                                        <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td align="right" valign="middle" class="flexibleContainerBox">
                                                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="max-width:100%;">
                                                                        <tr>
                                                                            <td align="right" valign="middle" class="flexibleContainerBox">
                                                                                <table class="flexibleContainerBoxNext" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="210" style="max-width:100%;">
                                                                                    <tr>
                                                                                        <td align="left" class="textContent">
                                                                                            <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSN7rd-ot8ZAUnwwvNbeiEZiduAcGow2siJGdT-nGCbBWrv3EbN4tGdE1xk" width="800" class="flexibleImage" alt="Text" title="Logo" />
                                                                                        </td>
                                                                                    </tr>
                                                                                </table>
                                                                            </td>
                                                                        </tr>
                                                                    </table>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </table>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                            <!-- // FLEXIBLE CONTAINER -->
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                <!-- // CENTERING TABLE -->
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- // END -->
                    </table>
                    <table bgcolor="#FFFFFF"  border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="800" id="emailBody">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="center" valign="top">
                                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="800" class="flexibleContainer">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td align="center" valign="top" width="500" class="flexibleContainerCell">
                                                        <!-- CONTENT TABLE // -->
                                                        <!--
                                                            The content table is the first element
                                                        that's entirely separate from the structural
                                                        framework of the email.
                                                        -->
                                                        <table border="0" cellpadding="30" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td align="center" valign="top" class="textContent">
                                                                    <h2 style="line-height:100%;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:34px;font-weight:normal;margin-bottom:5px;text-align:center;">An Article has been shared with you!</h2>
                                                                    <h3 style="text-align:center;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:24px;margin-bottom:0;line-height:135%;"><span style="color:#df5d5d;">User name</span>&nbsp;shared:</h3>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </table>
                                                        <!-- // CONTENT TABLE -->
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                            <!-- // FLEXIBLE CONTAINER -->
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                <!-- // CENTERING TABLE -->
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">
                                <!-- CENTERING TABLE // -->
                                <table border="0"  cellpadding="40" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="center" valign="top">
                                            <!-- FLEXIBLE CONTAINER // -->
                                            <table border="0" style="margin-top:-33px" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" width="600" height="222" class="flexibleContainer">
                                                <tr style="background:#eff0f2;">
                                                    <td valign="top" width="500" class="flexibleContainerCell">
                                                        <!-- CONTENT TABLE // -->
                                                        <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td align="left" valign="top" class="flexibleContainerBox">
                                                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="210" style="max-width:100%;">
                                                                        <tr>
                                                                            <td align="left" class="textContent">
                                                                                <img src="http://www.caribbeanbelleweddings.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/slide-circle-green.png" width="210" class="flexibleImage" style="max-width:100%;height:216px" alt="Text" title="Text" />
                                                                            </td>
                                                                        </tr>
                                                                    </table>
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td align="left" valign="center" class="flexibleContainerBox">
                                                                    <table class="flexibleContainerBoxNext" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="210" style="max-width:100%;">
                                                                        <tr>
                                                                            <td align="left" class="textContent">
                                                                                <h3 style="color:#5F5F5F;line-height:125%;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:20px;font-weight:normal;margin-top:0;margin-bottom:3px;text-align:left;">Tales of travelling and working abroad</h3>
                                                                                <div style="text-align:left;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:15px;margin-bottom:0;color:#5F5F5F;line-height:135%;">www.nytimes.com</div>
                                                                            </td>
                                                                        </tr>
                                                                    </table>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </table>
                                                        <!-- // CONTENT TABLE -->
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                            <!-- // FLEXIBLE CONTAINER -->
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                <!-- // CENTERING TABLE -->
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr bgcolor="#eef0f2">
                            <td align="center" valign="top">
                                <!-- CENTERING TABLE // -->
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="40" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                    <tr >
                                        <td align="center" valign="top">
                                            <!-- FLEXIBLE CONTAINER // -->
                                            <table border="0" cellpadding="30" cellspacing="0" width="500" class="flexibleContainer">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="padding-bottom:0;" valign="top" width="500" class="flexibleContainerCell">
                                                        <!-- CONTENT TABLE // -->
                                                        <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td align="center" valign="top" class="flexibleContainerBox">
                                                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="90" style="max-width:100%;">
                                                                        <tr>
                                                                            <td align="left" class="textContent">
                                                                                <img src="http://www.caribbeanbelleweddings.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/slide-circle-green.png" width="73" class="flexibleImageSmall" style="max-width:100%;" alt="Text" title="Text" />
                                                                            </td>
                                                                        </tr>
                                                                    </table>
                                                                </td>

                                                            </tr>
                                                        </table>
                                                        <!-- // CONTENT TABLE -->
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                            <!-- // FLEXIBLE CONTAINER -->
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                <!-- // CENTERING TABLE -->
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- // MODULE ROW -->
                        <!-- MODULE ROW // -->
                        <tr style="background:#eef0f2">
                            <td align="center" valign="top">
                                <!-- CENTERING TABLE // -->
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="center" valign="top">
                                            <!-- FLEXIBLE CONTAINER // -->
                                            <table border="0" cellpadding="30" cellspacing="0" width="500" class="flexibleContainer">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="padding-top:0;" align="center" valign="top" width="500" class="flexibleContainerCell">
                                                        <!-- CONTENT TABLE // -->
                                                        <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="flexibleContainer">
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td align="left" valign="top" class="textContent">
                                                                    <div style="text-align:left;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:15px;margin-bottom:0;margin-top:10px;color:#5F5F5F;line-height:135%;">Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus netus malesuada et fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante.</div>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </table>
                                                        <!-- // CONTENT TABLE -->
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                            <!-- // FLEXIBLE CONTAINER -->
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                <!-- // CENTERING TABLE -->
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- // MODULE ROW -->
                        <!-- MODULE ROW // -->
                        <tr style="background:#eef0f2">
                            <td align="center" valign="top">
                                <!-- CENTERING TABLE // -->
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="center" valign="top">
                                            <!-- FLEXIBLE CONTAINER // -->
                                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="800" class="flexibleContainer">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td valign="top" width="500" class="flexibleContainerCell">
                                                        <!-- CONTENT TABLE // -->
                                                        <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td align="left" valign="top" class="flexibleContainerBox">
                                                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="max-width:100%;">
                                                                        <tr>
                                                                            <td align="right" valign="middle" class="flexibleContainerBox">
                                                                                <table class="flexibleContainerBoxNext" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="210" style="max-width:100%;">
                                                                                    <tr>
                                                                                        <td align="left" class="textContent">
                                                                                            <img src="http://t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRIZb29YAMj68dNKayEUfR7KMIOJD8rmf1etLqqRDfI6f0XG_3H" width="800" class="flexibleImage" alt="Text" title="Logo" />
                                                                                        </td>
                                                                                    </tr>
                                                                                </table>
                                                                            </td>
                                                                        </tr>
                                                                    </table>
                                                                            </td>
                                                                        </tr>
                                                                    </table>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </table>
                                                        <!-- // CONTENT TABLE -->
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                            <!-- // FLEXIBLE CONTAINER -->
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                <!-- // CENTERING TABLE -->
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- // MODULE ROW -->
                        <!-- MODULE ROW // -->
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any suggestion will be helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

The fact is that Outlook uses Word for rendering the message bodies. The background properties are not supported in Word. You can read more about  supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties in the following series of articles in MSDN:

- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 1 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 2 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338200(v=office.12).aspx)

Hope it will help.